# More direct way to build dict from sql

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have the following code pattern, where I am trying to build a dictionary from a SQL output.

```
MAP_COLLECTION_ID_TO_INFO = {}
episodes = ItemInstance.objects.filter(content_type_id='TV Episode')
for e in episodes:
    MAP_COLLECTION_ID_TO_INFO[e.pk] = {
        'TitlePK': e.id,
        'TVSeriesPK': e.tv_series_id,
        'Provider': e.provider_id,
        'BaseLanguageID': e.base_language_id,
    }
```

Is there a way to put more of this work in SQL or the serialization of the SQL output? Rather than doing a forloop over the 2M items? If so, how would that be done?

```
The table structure is something like:

main_iteminstance
- id
- tv_series_id
- base_language_id
- provider_id
```

And the structure I'm trying to build is a map from the TitleID to all the info. For example:

```
{
    1: {'TitlePK': 1, 'TVSeriesPK': 5, 'Provider': 'Sony', 'BaseLanguageID': 'EN'},
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide at least table structure and the results you need?

Comment: @Switcher please see updated question.